# Check i Current Date is greater than other specified date javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to check if today date is greater than specified date say 26th march 2017 
note only one date is specified not both i researched on stack overflow the questions answer check between two specified date .
i want to check

```
if(current date > specified date) {
// do this 
}
```

i tried converting into day but it was not flexible . I dint understand well

Comment: Possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/6568620

Comment: i wrote in question other answers compare two specified dates not current date with other specifed date think before u answer

Comment: @RishabhAhuja I guess you should read answer more carefully new Date(); will give you current date The link by Mohamed Abbas is sufficient to close your answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

One of the solution i would suggest is moment.js library.

It provides Query functions like isBefore(), isSame() and isAfter().

```js
var today = moment('2010-10-20'),
     specifiedDate = moment('2010-10-21');
if(today.isBefore(specifiedDate)){
  console.log("Past Date");
}else{
  console.log("Future Date");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var specific_date = new Date('2017-03-26');
var current_date = new Date();
if(current_date.getTime() > specific_date.getTime())
{
    console.log('current_date date is grater than specific_date')
}
else
{
    console.log('current_date date is lower than specific_date')
}
```

Comment: It's not precise. What happens if they are equals? You have to write "Current_date date is lower than or equal to the specific date". Or you can add else if (current_date.getTime() == specific_date.getTime())

Answer (score 1):

Use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to handle dates,

ex:

```
moment().isAfter('2014-03-26T01:14:00Z') // true
moment().isAfter('2017-03-26T01:14:00Z') // false
```